# Get the MAX and MIN of a SUM in a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to get the MAX and MIN inside a SUM in SQL Server, but I can't get it in one query.

To get the MAX and MIN, I get them through the "Order by" ascending and descending of the sum, but I can not get it in one query, but in two yes

I'm taking the data in the following way:

```
Select CCO.CustomCuttingOrder,
CCO.CustomAPRWidth,
CCO.ManufacturingOrder,
CCO.ManufacturingPhase
FROM CustomCuttingOrder CCO
Where CCO.manufacturingOrder = '1368289'
```

The main result would be this:

```
CustomCuttingOrder   CustomAPRWidth                         
ManufacturingOrder ManufacturingPhase            
-------------------- --------------------------------------- ------------------------------------ 1                    47.00                                   1368289                        20 1                    47.00          
1368289                        20 1                    47.00          
1368289                        20 1                    47.00          
1368289                        20 2                    104.00         
1368289                        20 2                    47.00          
1368289                        20 2                    47.00          
1368289                        20 3                    104.00         
1368289                        20 3                    50.00          
1368289                        20 3                    50.00          
1368289                        20 4                    104.00         
1368289                        20 4                    104.00         
1368289                        20
```

Once I have the data, I have to do a SUM filtering by the CustomCuttingOrder, getting the minimum and maximum value.

For that I have made these two queries with TOP 1, which give me the MAX and MIN value grouped with the other fields and sorted in descending and ascending order.

First query:

```
Select TOP 1 
CCO.CustomCuttingOrder,
SUM(CCO.customAPRWidth) AS MAX,
CCO.manufacturingOrder,
CCO.manufacturingPhase 
from CustomCuttingOrder CCO
Where CCO.manufacturingOrder = '1368289'
GROUP BY CCO.CustomCuttingOrder, 
CCO.manufacturingOrder,
CCO.manufacturingPhase
ORDER BY CCO.customCuttingOrder desc
```

Result

```
CustomCuttingOrder   MAX                                     manufacturingOrder   manufacturingphase
-------------------- --------------------------------------- ------------------         --------
4                    208.00                                  1368289                        20
```

Second query:

```
Select TOP 1 CCO.CustomCuttingOrder,
SUM(CCO.customAPRWidth) AS MIN, 
CCO.manufacturingOrder,
CCO.manufacturingPhase 
from CustomCuttingOrder CCO
Where CCO.manufacturingOrder = '1368289'
GROUP BY CCO.CustomCuttingOrder, CCO.manufacturingOrder,CCO.manufacturingPhase
ORDER BY CCO.customCuttingOrder asc
```

Result:

```
CustomCuttingOrder   MIN                                    manufacturingOrder   manufacturingphase
-------------------- --------------------------------------- ------------------         --------
4                    188.00                                  1368289                        20
```

The result returned is OK:

But when I want to join the two queries through a UNION or UNION ALL, it doesn't let me do it:

```
Select TOP 1 
CCO.CustomCuttingOrder,
SUM(CCO.customAPRWidth) AS MAX,
CCO.manufacturingOrder,
CCO.manufacturingPhase 
from CustomCuttingOrder CCO
Where CCO.manufacturingOrder = '1368289'
GROUP BY CCO.CustomCuttingOrder, 
CCO.manufacturingOrder,
CCO.manufacturingPhase
ORDER BY CCO.customCuttingOrder desc

UNION

Select TOP 1 CCO.CustomCuttingOrder,
SUM(CCO.customAPRWidth) AS MIN, 
CCO.manufacturingOrder,
CCO.manufacturingPhase 

from CustomCuttingOrder CCO
Where CCO.manufacturingOrder = '1368289'
GROUP BY CCO.CustomCuttingOrder, CCO.manufacturingOrder,CCO.manufacturingPhase
ORDER BY CCO.customCuttingOrder asc
```

The expected result would be to get the MAX and MIN within the same query as follows:

Expected results:

```
CustomCuttingOrder   MAX              MIN                    manufacturingOrder   manufacturingphase
-------------------- --------------------------------------- ------------------         --------
4                    208.00           188.00                       1368289                20
```

Comment: I think you miss understand what `UNION` does; it combines 2 datasets into 1 dataset. If you have 2 datasets with 1 row each you get 1 dataset with *2* rows. The operator doesn't look at the 2 datasets, checks to see what different columns they have, and then puts into single arbitrary rows(s).

Comment: Ok, thank you, I was thinking to do this whit UNION @Larnu , but what alternative would there be to get this out?

Comment: Looks like need a JOIN not a UNION.